# parser returns nothing or wrong result, while parsing zara.com

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

Here is a simple code, taken from manual (for example)

```
include ('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.zara.com/ru/ru/%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B/%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B8-c269234.html');

foreach($html->find('img') as $element) { 
    echo $element->src . '<br>'; 
}
```

it returns nothing or a lot of srcs which are wrong and don't have images at all

what is the problem? why does it happen?
I don't get it at all

can you explain me or smth.

thank you in advance!

Comment: Because pictures are loaded via javascript.

Comment: @Glavić can I parse them in another way?